# Conditionally select a class in AngularJS with ng-class

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have two classes in an array as follows

```
$scope.userClasses = ["user-dashboard-dark", "user-dashboard-light"];
```

And my html code is

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-click="userClick(user)" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="user in usersList" style="cursor:pointer;">
        <div class="panel widget" ng-class="userClasses">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row row-table">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                        <img src="{{user.image || 'app/img/user/avatar03.png'}}" alt="Image" class="img-thumbnail img-circle img-responsive thumb64" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 text-center">
                        <h4 class="m0">{{user.userName}}</h4>
                        <em class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></em>
                        <span><small>{{user.email}}</small></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use first class(user-dashboard-dark) for the first time and for the rest I want to use second class(user-dashboard-light)

Answer (score 0):

Can try this:

```
<div ng-class="userClasses[0]"> {{user.userName}} </div>

<div ng-class="userClasses[1]"> {{user.email}} </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable $first inside the ng-repeat. $first is true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.
Your html code should look as follows:

```
<div class="row">
   <div ng-click="userClick(user)" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="user in usersList" style="cursor:pointer;">
      <div class="panel widget" ng-class="{'user-dashboard-dark' :$first, 'user-dashboard-light': !$first }">
         <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row row-table">
               <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                  <img src="{{user.image || 'app/img/user/avatar03.png'}}" alt="Image" class="img-thumbnail img-circle img-responsive thumb64" />
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-8 text-center">
                  <h4 class="m0">{{user.userName}}</h4>
                  <em class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></em>
                  <span><small>{{user.email}}</small></span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If your insisting to apply classes from an array then define a function in your controller that returns the right class according to $first:

```
  $scope.isFirstRow = function(first){
    return (first ? $scope.userClasses[0] : $scope.userClasses[1]);
  }
```

and in your html:

```
<div class="panel widget" ng-class="isFirstRow($first)">
```